# Android Studio Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have a problem with Android Studio, when I run AVD on the event log information it always says

> 11:17 Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed: vkBindBufferMemory2 not
>   found
>
> 11:17 Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed: vkBindImageMemory2 not
>   found
>
> 11:17 Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed:
>   vkGetDeviceGroupPeerMemoryFeatures not found
>
> 11:17 Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed: vkCmdSetDeviceMask not
>   found
>
> 11:17 Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed: vkCmdDispatchBase not
>   found
>
> 11:17 Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed:
>   vkGetImageMemoryRequirements2 not found
>
> 11:17 Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed:
>   vkGetBufferMemoryRequirements2 not found
>
> 11:17 Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed:
>   vkGetImageSparseMemoryRequirements2 not found
>
> 11:17 Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed: vkTrimCommandPool not
>   found
>
> 11:17 Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed:
>   vkCreateSamplerYcbcrConversion not found
>
> 11:17 Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed:
>   vkDestroySamplerYcbcrConversion not found
>
> 11:17 Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed:
>   vkCreateDescriptorUpdateTemplate not found
>
> 11:17 Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed:
>   vkDestroyDescriptorUpdateTemplate not found
>
> 11:17 Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed:
>   vkUpdateDescriptorSetWithTemplate not found
>
> 11:17 Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed:
>   vkGetDescriptorSetLayoutSupport not found
>
> 11:17 Emulator: createOrGetGlobalVkEmulation: Warning: Vulkan 1.1 APIs
>   missing from device
>
> 11:18 Emulator: deleteSnapshot: for default_boot

[image]

Comment: crash into the same issue, here's my hardware list:
CPU: AMD Ryzen 3700X
GPU: AMD 5700XT
Vulkan API Version(From amd gpu drive panel): 1.1.119

Comment: Latest info: uninstall AMD graphic drive solved this problem, AVD works like a charm.

Comment: Rather than posting a printscreen, including the relevant code as text is the better way to go.

Answer (score 14):

I have solved my problem by adapting this:

https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/05/emulator-2909-stable.html

It's a work around rather than a solution

```
# Here's how to disable Vulkan apps to talk to the emulator.

# Add the following lines to ~/.android/advancedFeatures.ini (create this file if it doesn't exist already):

Vulkan = off
GLDirectMem = on
```

My sistem:

- Linux Kernel: 5.4.6-2-MANJARO
- Android Q (10.0)
- Emulator 29.3.5

Comment: You need more details regarding how to adapt it.

Comment: Go to your .android folder and create a new file named 'advancedFeatures.ini'. Paste in the text above. This worked for me and got rid of the error warnings. I run an AMD 3900X CPU with an AMD GPU 5500XT on Windows 10.

On Windows 10 your .android folder is located in your user folder. Usually:

C:\Users\yourUserName

Answer (score 1):

Run into the same issue and here how I solve this, Launch Android Virtual Device with android studio puzzled me a lot, post my actions here just as a reference.

1. Uninstall latest Radeon GPU drive(`Adrenalin 2019 Edition 19.10.2 Optional`)
2. Install the latest Recommended drive(`Adrenalin 2019 Edition 19.9.2 Recommended (WHQL)`)
3. Enable the `Windows Hypervisor Platform` feature([Reference](https://superuser.com/a/1439435/1107641)).

now you can run x86 images in AVD.

And, don't know if some info related to this, since these words always are shown together, I also paste here.

1. Using `AMD RYZEN 3700X` and `AMD Radeon 5700XT` hardware.
2. enabled CPU Virtualization (called `AMD-V`) in BIOS([Reference](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Virtualization_Guide/sect-Virtualization-Troubleshooting-Enabling_Intel_VT_and_AMD_V_virtualization_hardware_extensions_in_BIOS.html))
3. Disabled `Hyper-v` in  `turn windows features on or off` (distinguish from `Windows Hypervisor Platform` above, they are quite different things)
4. Using the latest android studio(`version 3.5.1`)

Comment: Has raised an issue on the android studio bug report community, man there suggests using an older and stable GPU drive.

Comment: Hello, I have the exact same issue as OP, followed what you said, (now stable driver version is 19.10.2, and optional is 19.12.1, I'm using the stable) and I still have this issue

Comment: @MátéAntal try uninstall Radeon drives, see if you can run the emulator, or it can be another issue.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the advice in the IDE log, idea.log, worked to ...

2. Erase and re-download the emulator ($ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I just purchased a ryzen 5 laptop with vega 8 video and was having alot of problems running the Android 
Studio emulator in the end the problem was resolved and it was very simple.

1: enable SVM or other virtual machine setting in the BIOS
2: disable all hypervisor and virtual machine features by going to "Turn features on / off" in windows.
3: ensure you checkmark the AMD driver and uncheck HAXM in "SDK Tools" is SDK Manager.

And most important:

it is said that the latest update of android studio automatically installs the AMD driver once selected, however I found this not to be the case so the last step you need to do manually just to make sure.

4:run :  C:\users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver\silent_install.bat