# Error for Android Emulator: Deciding if GLDirectMem/Vulkan should be enabled

Tags: macos, android-studio, android-emulator

When I tried to run the project on Andriod Studio on mac, I got an internal error as below:

```
Andriod Emulator closed because of an internal error:
emuglConfig_init: blaclisted=0 has_guest_renderer=1

emuglConfig_init: auto-selected host based on conditions and UI preference 0

Deciding if GLDirectMem/Vulkan should be enabled. 
Selected renderer: 1API level: 27 host GPU blacklisted?1 
Host GPU selected, not enabling Vulkan because either API level is
Not enabling Vulkan here(Feature flag may be turned on manually)
```

Please look at the attached Screenshot of error for more details:

[image]

Comment: I am having the same issue. How did you resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, Andriod studio 3.5.1 doesn't support Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB (MacBook 2019). Please find [more information](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/android-applications-on-intel-architecture/topic/507657) here.

Comment: I have a 2018 MBP and this happens with that as well.

Comment: I have a 2017 MBP and it only happens if I create a custom resolution emulator device

Comment: Fun fact: some days it works, some day it don't (MacBook Pro 2016)

Answer (score 4):

solution source-> https://stackoverflow.com/a/63244455/16412512
You can work around it as indicated here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59715169/1796802 :
Create the file ~/.android/advancedFeatures.ini (for Windows users path should be C:\Users\Dane.android\advancedFeatures.ini) with the following content:
Here's how to disable Vulkan apps to talk to the emulator.

```
# Add the following lines to ~/.android/advancedFeatures.ini (create this file if it doesn't exist already):
# Vulkan = off
# GLDirectMem = on
```

Answer (score 2):

For my case, I solved the issue by updating the "Android Emulator" to the latest version from Android Studio > Window > SDK Manager > SDK Tools (Ensure that Android Emulator is updated to the latest version).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to update/install my **Intel VGA drivers**. Although Nvidia was installed

Comment: Here the question is about Macbook. You cannot update Intel HD Graphics drivers on a Mac. Apple provides the drivers using Software Update. You should always have the latest drivers by keeping your Mac up to date. There are also no unofficial Intel HD Graphics drivers for Mac. Unfortunately, NVIDIA currently cannot release a driver unless it is approved by Apple.