# Vulkan 1.1 APIs missing from device - Android Studio Emulator

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, manjaro

On Manjaro Linux.

Running Android Studio 3.6.3. Everything works great, but **when I try to launch any emulator I am getting this error:**

`Emulator: createOrGetGlobalVkEmulation: Warning: Vulkan 1.1 APIs missing from device`

I'm not having any driver issues outside of trying to use the Android Studio Emulator.

#### Studio SDK's installed:

[image: Android SDK's installed]

#### Vulkan driver's installed:

I have Radeon's Vulkan mesa driver installed in manjaro. I also have virtualization enabled for processor in BIOS.

#### Manjaro Information:

```
System:    Host: command Kernel: 5.4.40-1-MANJARO x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 
CPU:       Topology: 8-Core model: AMD Ryzen 7 2700X bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Zen+ rev: 2 L2 cache: 4096 KiB 
Graphics:  Device-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] 
           vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: amdgpu v: kernel bus ID: 0a:00.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.org 1.20.8 driver: amdgpu resolution: <xdpyinfo missing> 
           OpenGL: renderer: Radeon RX 580 Series (POLARIS10 DRM 3.35.0 5.4.40-1-MANJARO LLVM 10.0.0) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.0.6 
           direct render: Yes
```

Answer (score 22):

You can work around it as indicated here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59715169/1796802 :

Create the file `~/.android/advancedFeatures.ini`
(for Windows users path should be `C:\Users\Dane\.android\advancedFeatures.ini`) with the following content:

```
# Here's how to disable Vulkan apps to talk to the emulator.

# Add the following lines to ~/.android/advancedFeatures.ini (create this file if it doesn't exist already):

Vulkan = off
GLDirectMem = on
```

Comment: This answer is helpful if you are getting `amdvlk.dll` not found in Android Studio 4.2.2.

Comment: This worked. But now CPU usage is going insane. Thanks anyway.

Comment: you are definitely a lifesaver, I been stuck at this for more than 24hours