# Android Emulator give error about vulkan-1.dll not found

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, adb, android-virtual-device

Android Emulator not starting, I have new installation of android studio and AVD when launching through the command prompt it gives this error,

[image: ERROR IMAGE]

I have my emulator setup as 2GB ram, and with graphics as softwares GLES 2.0, Tried almost everything available but it is not working, What could be the solution for it?

Comment: Start cmd.exe with Administrative privilege and run again

Comment: No luck @UsamaAltaf getting the same error

Comment: try this solution for Emulater v30.7.5 [https://stackoverflow.com/a/68416846/2536025](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68416846/2536025)

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be due to many reasons. The first thing you gotta try is disable Vulkan completely (it's not a solution, but rather a workaround).
Check this solution : [Disabling Vulkan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59715169/14910363)

Second of all, you could try disabling the QuickBoot feature all together, add this command `-no-snapshot`. Learn more here [Emulator CMD Commands](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline)

EDIT: You can also try playing around with the additional System commands such as Engine command and GPU command (mentioned in the link above).
For example, you can try switching Acceleration off `-accel off`
Or try using the older QEMU engine `-engine classic`
Also play around with the GPU mode.
Good luck.

Comment: I have already added that, Already running on cold boot, both solution not working

Comment: engine selection is depricated in emulator version 30.3